# How does BabelJS achieve tail recursion?

Tags: javascript, tail-recursion, babeljs

How does Babel implement tail recursion?

How does this [transpiled es5 code](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=function%20factorial(n%2C%20acc%20%3D%201)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22use%20strict%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(n%20%3C%3D%201)%20return%20acc%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20factorial(n%20-%201%2C%20n%20*%20acc)%3B%0A%7D) work?

Comment: This is probably not a question for SO, but every recursive call can be rewritten to a iterative loop (and vice versa). Babel isn't doing anything special.

Comment: Thanks @Lapixx. I understand the recursive call vs. iterative loop part, I wasn't getting the *tail* part, but I think I get it now, it's a label, and instead of doing a function call, it does a `continue` back at the `_function` label.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thought that I would post a detailed explanation, to allow those landing here from Google to hopefully be able to come to a faster understanding more quickly.

Note that the following explanation was derived from what I can tell from the code (no consultation with the author of Babel or other experts in its code was performed), so it is unknown whether the meaning I derived was the intended meaning of @sebmck or others who contributed to this transformation.

```
"use strict"; // ES2015/ES6 modules are assumed to be in strict mode.

function factorial(_x2) {
    // This variable is the list of arguments to factorial.
    // Since factorial may be called again from within this function
    // (but must be called indirectly to prevent call stack growth),
    // a custom arguments-like variable must be maintained.
    var _arguments = arguments;

    // _again equals true when the original factorial function should be called
    // once more.
    var _again = true;

    // This line creates a labeled while loop, use to allow continuing this
    // specific loop, without the requirement of having no nested while loops
    // Nested while loops would cause a "continue" statement within them to
    // execute them, not this loop.
    _function: while (_again) {

        // The variable used in the original factorial function was called "n",
        // this method allows Babel to not rename it, but simply assign the
        // possibly modified first argument of the factorial function to it.
        var n = _x2;

        // Temporal dead zone (TDZ) mechanic
        acc = undefined;

        // The "use strict" directive from the original function
        "use strict";

        // Beginning of user code, this is always inserted to ensure that if
        // this is the final run, the while loop will not run again.
        _again = false;

        // This is Babel's default argument handling. The steps, in order, are:
        // 1. Make sure that there will not be an out-of-bounds access for the
        //    undefined check.
        // 2. Check if the second argument to the current iteration is undefined,
        //    if yes: the default value is `1`, if no, use the value of the first argument.
        var acc = _arguments.length <= 1 || _arguments[1] === undefined ? 1 : _arguments[1];

        // Input code - no modifications.
        if (n <= 1) return acc;

        // The following three lines are the call to factorial() within factorial
        // in the input code. The first line assigns the new arguments, as well
        // as updating the _x2 variable to it's new value. The second line
        // overrides the assignment in the beginning of the loop.
        // The third line brings the loop back to the beginning.
        _arguments = [_x2 = n - 1, n * acc];
        _again = true;
        continue _function;
    }
}
```